# how to save large files inside the data base.?

Tags: java, mysql, database, servlets, file-upload

I am using JSP form to upload and Servlet to store a large-sized file in a MySQL database. and because i am new to Java in general, i need a really urgent help. 
I tried to store the file in a String value but i got error that string index is out of boundary.

I have the database table Files which has (varchar File_Name, Blob File_data, Varchar File_Date) .
And i need to store the uploaded file inside the

I had this code in servlet:
** BTW : i have no idea why  "DiskFileUpload, parseRequest " have strikethrough line ?

```
 try {
         InputStream uploadedFile = null;

         <strike>DiskFileUpload</strike> fu = new </strike>DiskFileUpload</strike>();
        // If file size exceeds, a FileUploadException will be thrown
        fu.setSizeMax(10000000);

        List fileItems = fu.<strike>parseRequest</strike>(request);
        Iterator itr = fileItems.iterator();

        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            FileItem fi = (FileItem) itr.next();

            //Check if not form field so as to only handle the file inputs
            //else condition handles the submit button input
            if (!fi.isFormField()) {  // If the form fiel is a file
                uploadedFile = fi.getInputStream();
            }
```

What type of data should I convert uploadFile cvariable to be able to store it in a Blob attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strike through means API is deprecated and those classes/methods may not work as expected.

Storing file to database, you need to store the content as bytes in blob filed. See this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065687/store-java-object-as-blob-in-mysql-strange-error). Even though it is related to some error, OP posted code on how to do this.

Comment: and how can I overcome this problem ?